# Convert an array of UIBarButtonItem to array of ToolbarItem

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I'm new to swiftUI. We have both UIKit and swiftUI code in our project and we have some custom logic to add few UIBarButtonItem. I need to pass viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems array from UIKit code to a separate swiftUI module and then create toolBar with these rightBarButtonItems.

```
struct ToolBarItems: ToolbarContent {

    let barButtons: [UIBarButtonItem]
    init(barButtons: [UIBarButtonItem]) {
        self.barButtons = barButtons
    }
    
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            Text("principal Title")
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbarButtons: some ToolbarContent {
        ForEach(barButtons) { item in
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(item.title!) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives errors "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'". Not sure how to do this conversion.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `ForEach` is not `ToolbarContent`. You can create a `ToolbarItemGroup` instead, which takes a `@ViewBuilder`, and you can put the `ForEach` in the `@ViewBuilder`:

```
struct UIKitBarButtons: ToolbarContent {
    ...

    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            ForEach(barButtons) { item in
                Button(item.title!) { ... }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you would need `extension UIBarButtonItem: Identifiable {}` for the `ForEach` to work.

However, `item.title` is main actor-isolated, but `ToolbarContent.body` is not. While you can isolate `ToolbarContent.body` to `@MainActor`, you would end up implementing a non-isolated protocol requirement with an actor-isolated property, which is potentially not safe.

I would create my own struct to represent a "navigation bar item". For example, if you are only interested in the title, image, and action of the `UIBarButtonItem`, I would create a struct like this:

```
struct NavBarButton: Identifiable {
    let id: ObjectIdentifier
    let title: LocalizedStringKey?
    let image: UIImage?
    let action: () -> Void
    
    @MainActor
    init(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        id = ObjectIdentifier(barButtonItem)
        title = barButtonItem.title.map(LocalizedStringKey.init(_:))
        image = barButtonItem.image
        self.action = {
            guard let selector = barButtonItem.action else {
                return
            }
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(selector, to: barButtonItem.target, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this in a custom `ToolbarContent` like this:

```
struct UIKitBarButtons: ToolbarContent {
    let barButtons: [NavBarButton]

    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            ForEach(barButtons) { item in
                Button {
                    item.action()
                } label: {
                    if let title = item.title {
                        Text(title)
                    }
                    if let image = item.image {
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `body` of a `View`, you can then do:

```
.toolbar {
    UIKitBarButtons(barButtons: uiBarButtonItems.map(NavBarButton.init))
}
```

`NavBarButton.init` is main actor-isolated, but so is `View.body`, so this is okay.

Comment: When I tried this approach, barButtonItem.target is not getting set and hence the action is not working.

Comment: @user1165756 well why did you not set the target? How do you want to pass the action? You can pass a closure to `NavBarButton` if you want. But it won’t work with `primaryAction` since you can’t directly invoke the closure of a `UIAction`.